# Grouping pandas dataframe by column specificity to row values - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of this type:

```
                 id   1   2   3   4   5  
                  A  10  40  80  12  50
                  B  20  60  70  77  60
                  C  30  15  50  20  60
                  C  30  15  20  45  43 
                  B  50 100  70  77  32
                  C  30  15  20  80  21
                  A  50 100  10  12  50
```

Is there a way to group it somehow to show which columns are specific for which id? For example, we can see that all of the values corresponding to the id 'C' in the first column equal to 30; similarly, column 3 is pretty 'B' id specific - all of the values are the same for 'B' in column 3 etc. Same for column 5 and id 'A'.

So, there are columns specific for each id; is there a way to group them somehow and for each id visualise/list columns specific to each of them?

Comment: can you show us a sample output you are looking for?

Comment: I am trying figure that out myself haha; I think a dictionary with column ids as keys and column names specific to these ids as values? {'A': 4,5; 'B': 3,4; 'C': ... etc}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(df.melt('id')
 .groupby(['id', 'variable'])
 .agg(lambda x: x.max() if x.max() == x.min() else None)
 .unstack())
```

result

```
    value
variable    1    2    3     4    5
id                  
A           NaN  NaN  NaN   12.0 50.0
B           NaN  NaN  70.0  77.0 NaN
C           30.0 15.0 NaN   NaN  NaN
```

or

```
(df.melt('id')
 .groupby(['id', 'variable'])
 .agg(lambda x: x.max() if x.max() == x.min() else None)
 .dropna().astype('int'))
```

result:

```
             value
id  variable    
A   4        12
    5        50
B   3        70
    4        77
C   1        30
    2        15
```

Comment: Wow, that worked; the only thing is that in my actual dataset I have quite small values (0.01 etc) and the values that were printed for each id were, as a result rounded to either 0 or 1. Is there a way to specify somehow the number of decimals by any chance?

Comment: remove `.astype('int')` in my second code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double groupby to aggregate the data as sets and define a threshold of a number of values to keep to define uniqueness:

```
thresh = 1

(df.melt('id', var_name='col')
   .groupby(['col', 'id'], as_index=False)['value']
   .agg(frozenset)
   .loc[lambda d: d['value'].str.len().le(thresh)]
   .groupby(['value', 'col'])['id']
   .agg(set)
   .loc[lambda s: s.str.len().eq(1)]
)
```

Output:

```
value  col
(30)   1      {C}
(15)   2      {C}
(70)   3      {B}
(12)   4      {A}
(77)   4      {B}
(50)   5      {A}
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Example with a threshold of 2 values:

```
value      col
(10, 50)   1      {A}
(50, 20)   1      {B}
           3      {C}
(30)       1      {C}
(40, 100)  2      {A}
(100, 60)  2      {B}
(15)       2      {C}
(80, 10)   3      {A}
(70)       3      {B}
(12)       4      {A}
(77)       4      {B}
(50)       5      {A}
(32, 60)   5      {B}
Name: id, dtype: object
```